# Error when trying add data to RavenDb

Tags: ravendb, autofac

I'm using autofac and the interfaces are correctly resolved but this code fails with "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8081"

```
using (var store = GetService<IDocumentStore>())
{
    using (var session = store.OpenSession())
    {
        session.Store(new Entry { Author = "bob", Comment = "My son says this", EntryId = Guid.NewGuid(), EntryTime = DateTime.Now, Quote = "I hate you dad." });
        session.SaveChanges();
    }
 }
```

Here is the registration

```
builder.Register<IDocumentStore>(c =>
        {
            var store = new DocumentStore { Url = "http://localhost:8081" };
            store.Initialize();
            return store;
        }).SingleInstance();
```

When I navigate to `http://localhost:8081` I do get the silverlight management UI. Although I'm running a Windows VM and vmware and Silverlight5 don't play together.  That's another issue entirely.  Anyways does anyone see what I'm doing wrong here or what I should be doing differently?  Thanks for any code, tips, or tricks.

On a side note, can I enter some dummy records from a command line interface? Any docs or examples of how I can do that?

Thanks All.

Answer (score 0):

Just curious, are you switching RavenDB to listen on 8081?  The default is 8080.  If you're getting the management studio to come up, I suspect you are.

I'm not too familiar with autofac but, it looks like you're wrapping your singleton DocumentStore in a using statement.

Try:

```
using (var session = GetService<IDocumentStore>().OpenSession())
{
}
```

As far as dummy records go, the management studio will ask you if you want to generate some dummy data if your DB is empty.  If you can't get silverlight to work in the VM, I'm not sure if there's another automated way to do it.

Perhaps using smuggler:

http://ravendb.net/docs/server/administration/export-import

But you'd have to find something to import.